Understand RGB565 values
I got an image 320x240 and tried to understand the process on how the RGB5655 works. I convert the image to byte array (2 bytes per pixel) the byte array is quite large (153600 values) and I just gonna put the first ones:
0x63, 0x08, 0x83, 0x08, 0xa4, 0x08, 0xa4, 0x08, 0xa4, 0x08, 0xa4, 0x08, 0xc5, 0x08, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x08, 0xc5, 0x08, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc5, 0x10, 0xc6, 0x10, 0xc6, 0x10, 0xc6, 0x10, 0xe6, 0x10, 0xe6, 0x10, 0xe6, 0x10, 

I though that the rgb565 value was like this:
 first uint16 value = 0x63 << 8 + 0x08`
 second uint16 value = 0x83<<8 + 0x08

to check this I use an image to RGB565 converter and see this:
6300,8308,a408,a408,a408,a408,a408,c408
a408,a408,a508,a508,a508,c508,a508,a508
c508,c508,c508,c508,c608,c608,e610,e610
e610,e610,e610,0611,0611,0611,e610,c608
c610,a510,a508,a508,a408,a408,a408,a408

which is not like I though it was. It seems that the first value of the array is left alone and then takes from the 2 and third to get the uint16 value, but...here is the question, why is there a  fifth uint16 a408 IF ONLY there is 4 in the array? and then is a 0xc510 value in the array BUT in the RGB565 there is 0xc408?
Could someone explain this process or point me to some references?
Regards
Gastón
P.S I used this link to get the byte array
I already tried to get the first values of RGB565 by equation but is there not relationship between the values I got and the values I get from the converter RGB565

Forget the image converter.  Post the actual data from the image.  If it's a bitmap, the values are stored BLUE then GREEN then RED.  A 16-bit value would then mean that the leftmost 5 bits are blue, the next 6 bits are green, and the last 5 bits are red.  The data may be stored red, green, blue...but that's an easy fix if it doesn't look right in the final application.

5 + 6 + 5 = 16 bits. The RGB values are all stored in one 16 bit integer. red = rgb565 >> 11 & 0x1F, green = rgb565 >> 5 & 0x3F, blue = rgb565 & 0x1F. Unless it's really BGR565, in which case just flip the red and blue names.

I forgot the final shift. After the above results, red and blue need to be left-shifted 3, and green left-shifted 2 (ex: green = green << 2)

thanks for ur answers, and I understand how to get the R G B values, but as I put above, I can't understand  how the RGB565 value is obtain. As I put above the array byte is uint8 size, so 2 bytes are needed to get the uint16 value,. I convert those values to uint16 by this the above equation and tried to generated image and nothing is displayed (just dots). Why the RGB565 from the converter is different from the values if i do uin8<<8 + uint8?

@GastonMelo How are you getting the image data bytes?  Are you using something?  If it was in bitmap format you can grab the values directly without having to do anything, just reading the pixel offset from the info at the beginning of the file.

@GastonMelo I'm not at all familiar with JPG format, but an online viewer says that the pixel data is YCbCr.  I recently converted a JPG to BMP and then converted that RGB888 data to RGB565.  Is that what you want to do?  Was the first time I did it, but it's not difficult.  Lots of image viewers can convert to BMP.  Then you just need the BMP format (from Wikip) to find where the pixel data are.  The data is stored as one byte of blue, one byte of green, one byte of red, etc.  Yes, the RGB order is reversed.

@GastonMelo I just did this and wrote the data to a 230x320 TFT display.  It looks nice.  I suggest you take that approach I mentioned.

Convert the JPG to BMP format using your favorite image application.  Windows Paint will do it, and whatever Linux has standard will do it as well.
Then, you can pull the pixel data directly out of the BMP file.  The conversion will most likely produce an image with 24 bits-per-pixel, but you can find that answer in the header info of the BMP file.  Also in there is the location of the pixel data.  Look up the Wikipedia page for "BMP format".  It's simple to understand, just from wiki's image of the format.
If 24-bit, the data will be one byte of blue, one byte of green, one byte of red, etc...to the end of the file.  Yes, the data is stored BGR instead of RGB.
That data you now have is RGB888.  You can convert it easily enough to RGB565.  I have a very recent thread on here (StackOverflow) showing three different conversion algorithms.
Here's my quick attempt.  I didn't bother rotating the image.  LCD image looks better than my terrible camera allows.


Thanks for the reply, but maybe I can't explain OK. How the RGB565 conversion from array to uint16 works? How is it getting the bytes from the array and do the math to get the uint16? I tried to take 2 consecutives uint8 bytes and do this math: uint8*256 + uint8 but this only give me a noise image. NOT this image you get in the display.
From the first post u will se that the RGB565 converter online do some math to get those uint8 bytes correct and get the correct image, but how? This converter takes 2 consecutives uint8 bytes from the array? or use random uint8 from the array?

@GastonMelo First of all, you can't get RGB data directly out of a JPG.  That's not how the JPG format works.  Second, I don't think you're properly explained how you're getting the pixel data and what you want to end up with.

I printed my data to output as the image was rendered, and you appear to have the bytes reversed.  This probably comes from not understanding that some encodings are "big-endian" and some are "little-endian".
6300,8308

should be
0063,0883


@Gaston Melo Please post back if you're still having a problem or if one of the answers is the solution.
